# How to find the vector of reflection of a ray from a plane?

Tags: c#

I have a vector that falls on a plane. I know that she exactly falls on the plane and I know the point of the fall. I need to find a reflection vector.

The plane is represented by 3 points on it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    public static Vector3 GetReflectedVector(Vector3 direction,Vector3 vert0, Vector3 vert1, Vector3 vert2)
    {
        Vector3 normalizeDirection = Normalize(direction);

        Vector3 planeNormal = Normalize(Cross(vert1 - vert0, vert0 - vert2));

        double dot = Dot(normalizeDirection, planeNormal);

        double mod = VectorModule(planeNormal);

        double pr = dot / mod;

        Vector3 projection = planeNormal * (float)pr * 2f;

        return direction - projection;
    }
```

Here such logic (should be):

1. obtain a normal to the plane {vert0, vert1, vert2};
2. obtain the projection of direction on the normal
3. double the resulting vector
4. subtract the received from the source vector dir.

Comment: The angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection.

Comment: This is understandable. I need to find this very vector

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
    public static Vector3 GetReflectedVector(Vector3 direction,Vector3 vert0, Vector3 vert1, Vector3 vert2)
    {
        Vector3 normalizeDirection = Normalize(direction);

        Vector3 planeNormal = Normalize(Cross(vert1 - vert0, vert0 - vert2));

        return CombineVector(normalizeDirection, planeNormal, 1, (float)(-2 * Dot(normalizeDirection, planeNormal)));
    }

    private static Vector3 CombineVector(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2, float f1, float f2)
    {
        Vector3 vector3;

        vector3.X = (f1 * v1.X) + (f2 * v2.X);
        vector3.Y = (f1 * v1.Y) + (f2 * v2.Y);
        vector3.Z = (f1 * v1.Z) + (f2 * v2.Z);

        return vector3;
    }
```